# View Controller in Android

Tags: android, view, viewcontroller

If I have Three viewcontroller classes A, B and C, I have two buttons in class A one navigates me to Class B and second navigates me to Class C. But when I come back either from class B or C .... I have to give an alert view from which class I am coming back (without using NSNotification Centre).

Answer (score 1):

You can use startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode) to call B and C.
Then in the onActivityResult() you have to check the requestCode to show alert dialog.

Please check this link : http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12204/onactivityresult-android-tutorial/

Comment: but if will press back how can I get startActivityforResult as alert

Comment: When pressing back button, the onActivityResult() not called ?